# MPV to play videos with a geometry

Tags: bash, video, bash-scripting, mpv

I have YOCTO build and I have integrated the mpv to the image. I need to test something so, I wrote a script that could play videos with a certain width and height and position on the screen but mpv always the videos full screen, this is the script that I have used

Is there an option for mpv to overcome this

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the width and height
width=250
height=250

# Launch the first video
mpv --geometry=${width}x${height}+0+0 video1.mp4 &

# Launch the second video
mpv --geometry=${width}x${height}+${width}+0 video2.mp4 &

# Launch the third video
mpv --geometry=${width}x${height}+0+${height} video3.mp4 &

# Launch the fourth video
mpv --geometry=${width}x${height}+${width}+${height} video4.mp4 &
```

Comment: Which mpv version? Did you try with `--no-config` to eliminate conflict with that?

Comment: @Destroy666 version  is mpv 0.34.1, and yes I have also tried with --no-config